# What happens when c++ encounters the diamond issue

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Coming from a java background I have never encountered the diamond problem where multiple inheritance can cause overriding problems as described in detail at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem

But if this problem occurs will the c++ runtime complain or is it random which implementation of the super class method will be invoked ?

I've read the 'Mitigation' part of article but did'nt fully understand it.

Comment: Doesn't this article explain what happens under the section *Mitigation*?

Comment: Did you read the article that you link to? It explicitly says, "C++ requires stating explicitly which parent class the feature to be used is invoked from i.e. 'Worker::Human.Age'." (Not very well-written, I admit, but if you read and didn't understand it, then you should say that, or else you can expect to get an answer that just quotes back at you the text you already failed to understand!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will catch a program encountering the diamond problem by diagnosing any ambiguity.

One solution is to remove the ambiguity. This can be done when referring to members by using explicit name qualification:

```
struct B {
    int bar;
};

struct D1 : B {};
struct D2 : B {};

struct E : D1, D2 {};

int main() {
    E e;
    e.D1::bar = 1; // explicitly set D1::bar, not D2::bar.
}
```

Or if you want to access a base sub-object as in: `B *b = new E;` It's ambiguous whether you want the base sub-object from D1 or D2. Using an explicit cast to one of those intermediate types resolves the ambiguity.

```
B *b = static_cast<D2*>(new E);
```

Also note that down-casting from a B* to an E* is not possible to do statically; the compiler doesn't know which B is being pointed to so it doesn't statically know how to adjust the pointer to get back to E. This is where dynamic_cast becomes necessary.

```
E *e = new E;
B *b1 = static_cast<D1*>(e);
B *b2 = static_cast<D2*>(e);
assert(b1 != b2);
assert(dynamic_cast<E*>(b1) == dynamic_cast<E*>(b2));
assert(e == dynamic_cast<E*>(b1));
```

Another solution is to sidestep the issue with virtual inheritance, thus avoiding multiple base sub-objects of the same type.

```
struct B {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual ~B() = default;
    int bar;
};

struct D1 : virtual B {};
struct D2 : virtual B {};

struct E : D1, D2 {
    virtual void foo() override {
        bar = 1; // no ambiguity because there's only a single B base sub-object
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is caught by the compiler. There is an example provided by http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/mi-diamond.html

```
class Base {
public:
protected:
  int data_;
};

class Der1 : public Base {  };

class Der2 : public Base {  };

class Join : public Der1, public Der2 {
public:
  void method()
  {
      data_ = 1; //g++ error: reference to ‘data_’ is ambiguous
  }
};

int main()
{
  Join* j = new Join();
  Base* b = j; //g++ error: ‘Base’ is an ambiguous base of ‘Join’
}
```